# Function pointer to GCC target builtin functions (sometimes) generate linkage errors

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, ld

In the process of writing a debugger I encountered a difficult to track down linker error, which this following crazy and contrived function will demonstrate.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
    (&main + (&__builtin_exit - &main)*(n/128))(++n);
}
```

This function compiles and works as expected.

Substituting `__builtin_exit` with any of the x86 target specific builtin instructions that would either pause or surreptitiously halt the program instead generate linkage errors during compilation (`` ...undefined reference to `__builtin_ia32. ..` ``).

Using the builtin functions in an inline fashion (without a pointer to the function) of course work fine.

Other classes of GCC builtins are alternate cooperative and link without errors or generate a similar linkage error.

Comment: Even if it weren't for taking the address of builtins, this program has about the highest density of undefined behavior I've ever seen. There is no reasoning to be had about this program. It's just nonsense.

Comment: If you want to kill program, easier way is to write something into volatile pointer, equal to NULL.

Comment: @R Undefined behavior wrt. the Standard can be well-defined wrt. a particular implementation like gcc.  And this question is obviously about gcc behavior.

Comment: What does `gcc` have to say about using `n` and `++n` without an intervening sequence point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

builtin functions are usually not like normal functions. They are called in the same syntax as normal functions, but unlike normal functions, most of builtins are inlined by the compiler. They are used to insert small sequences of asm code in the place of call.

There are several kinds of builtins, and some of builtins, like `__builtin_exit` are "library builtins", check the [`gcc/builtins.def` file](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/builtins.def;h=5a76ba3291ef7ea2d91e1dfb437871899271e0fa;hb=HEAD)

```
  80 /* A library builtin (like __builtin_strchr) is a builtin equivalent
  81    of an ANSI/ISO standard library function.  In addition to the
  82    `__builtin' version, we will create an ordinary version (e.g,
  83    `strchr') as well.  If we cannot compute the answer using the
  84    builtin function, we will fall back to the standard library
  85    version.  */
  86 #undef DEF_LIB_BUILTIN
  87 #define DEF_LIB_BUILTIN(ENUM, NAME, TYPE, ATTRS)        \
  88   DEF_BUILTIN (ENUM, "__builtin_" NAME, BUILT_IN_NORMAL, TYPE, TYPE,    \
  89                true, true, false, ATTRS, true, true)

  23 /*   DEF_BUILTIN (ENUM, NAME, CLASS, TYPE, LIBTYPE, BOTH_P,
  24                   FALLBACK_P, NONANSI_P, ATTRS, IMPLICIT, COND)

  33    Some builtins are actually two separate functions.  For example,
  34    for `strcmp' there are two builtin functions; `__builtin_strcmp'
  35    and `strcmp' itself.  Both behave identically.  Other builtins
  36    define only the `__builtin' variant.  If BOTH_P is TRUE, then this
  37    builtin has both variants; otherwise, it is has only the first
  38    variant.

  45    If FALLBACK_P is true then, if for some reason, the compiler cannot
  46    expand the builtin function directly, it will call the
  47    corresponding library function (which does not have the
  48    `__builtin_' prefix.  */
```

So, when you use `__builtin_exit` and take its address, it is converted into usage of library function `exit()` (which is defined in libc), because gcc  "*cannot compute the answer using the builtin function*".

Here is definition of `__builtin_exit` from the same file.

```
 699 DEF_LIB_BUILTIN        (BUILT_IN_EXIT, "exit", BT_FN_VOID_INT, ATTR_NORETURN_NOTHROW_LIST)
```

For `DEF_GCC_BUILTIN` kind of builtins, taking address is prohibited, because there are no such function defined in the libraries or CRT, and if gcc can't inline it, the function will be undefined and broke linking.

Comment: PS, @zv_, your RARVM software is great!